# How Database handles the Disk Block while it is control by OS

Tags: database, operating-system

I am not clear how database system control the disk blocks. I have read that the data which are related, put them in the same or nearby block. How it is possible for a database system(an application software). What I know is disk block is maintained by the OS so whatever algorithm is implemented in the OS it would allocate the disk block according to that.

If I am wrong, please correct me. I am novice in that.

Comment: One thing that I need to make aware that `Darabases are equivalent to OS`. Don't consider them merely as an application software! They do have their own concurrency algorithms,data implementation independent of computer OS and all! so,you are wrong in assuming that `disk block is maintained by the OS so whatever algorithm is implemented in the OS it would allocate the disk block according to that.` The database may share disk-related information to the kernel directly for sure as the name itself reveals `database`---complete management of data!!!

Comment: @Shekhar... Database can't be equal to OS.. May be it's a system software but system software itself need OS API to interact with the hardware(like OS need driver of that device to communicate with that device). There is no dbms that can be install individually without OS and once OS is installed every IO is done in kernel mode so dbms can't do any IO without OS system call.

Comment: I guess you are not aware of working capabilities of database then. It is indeed working like autonomous software which obviously takes the help from kernel. I nowhere mentioned that databases are OS,but their fundamental working capabilities and management of data is kinda equivalent(similar) to OS,not equal! Also,it depends on kernel to run in kernel mode but that interrupt is a higher prioritised system call which bypasses other processes or requests... @JatinKhurana! BTW,please confirm it from someone else,I might be wrong!

Comment: @shekhar ... tell me one database name underlying which no OS is there... and you are saying that they are equivalent to OS in terms os data management but in today system... everything IO operation is an interrupt(Interrupt based IO if u don't know read some Computer Architecture book)...so disk IO is also an interrupt and all Interrupt handling is done by OS(kernel).. so how it is possible for a database to handle the disk block structure.... don't say anything without proper reasoning about that... or put my reasoning wrong....

Comment: I'd like to draw your attention towards that I/O interrupts are themselves called up from subroutines of `Databases like Oracle,etc.` and thereby processes the data as they need and kernel simply schedules and handles these operations. The lower subroutines of databases are in action;---hence, we just can't install database without administrator rights! Again, I might be wrong! Also, please study about Oracle architecture and all!

Comment: Database can't call the IO routine . it tell the OS to do all the task by setting some environment variable(like we can change the disk block size by setting some environment variable). read the following link.... http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/iodesign.htm#PFGRF95223   anyway thanks to promote me to look into the Oracle implementation. Now I got everything

Comment: Roughly I was attributing the same @JatinKhurana. Anyway, thanks for sharing the link! I'll go through it.